# Integration by substitution: What formula can I refer to?

Tags: integration

When I am trying to integrate a composite function $f(g(x))$ that is multiplied by $g'(x)$, then there's a formula for that in my book. It's simply $F(g(x)) + C$.

But what if $g'(x)$ isn't there?

I'm trying to solve a problem like that, and it's obviously pretty easy with $u$ substitution.... but what formula can I refer to? My teacher doesn't want to see me do any of that method where I treat $\mathrm{d}u/\mathrm{d}x$ as a fraction, so while I can use it to figure out the problem, I have to refer to a more general formula.

Which one?

I've heard of one where the integral of $f(g(x))$ is $f(u) \cdot h'(u)$ where $h$ is the inverse of $g$, but that makes zero sense to me, and it doesn't work in the current problem I am doing.

Comment: What is the current problem you're working on?

Comment: Here's my problem. If I have a g(x) = x/(f(x)... then I can set u = f(x), say du = f '(x)dx, do some manipulation if necessary and get g(u) = 1/u .... easy to take the integral of, but that algebraic manipulation I did in order to get rid of ALL x's in g(x) and replace them with U's only.... I can't "show" that algebraic manipulation without the du/dx method where I treat it as a fraction... but I can't do that according to my teacher, so really no clue how I can explain to him that x/f(x) becomes 1/u and not x/u (the latter is what you'd expect to see based on the formula alone).

Answer (score 1):

There is none.

For example, let $f(x)=e^x$, and $g(x)=x^2$. So, if your formula exists, there would be a solution to:
$$\int e^{x^2} \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x$$
But, as it turns out, there isn't. (At least, there is no *elementary* solution. "Elementary" means that it can be written in terms of $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, exponentiation, trig functions and their inverses, etcetera.)

Comment: I don't have a proof that $\int e^{x^2} \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x$ has no solution, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are refering to the chain rule $(f(g(x))' = f(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$. If there is no $g'(x)$ you cannot use this rule.

Is your assigment $\int f(g(x))\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x$ or something specific like $\int \sin(x^2)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x$?